# RxJS, advice with lettable operators

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-lettable-operators

I'm getting lost with the new lettable operators.

I succeeded trying to use `mergeMap` :

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

But I don't know how to import operators such as `finally` :

```
import { ? } from 'rxjs/?';
```

Where is this operator ? Is there a rule to find each of the ones you need ?

Comment: Google "rxjs lettable operators", click on the first link, tada: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: Oh well, thank you, didn't know the name changed. Would you make an answer so that I can mark it as resolved  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `finally` is a JavaScript keyword and thus can't be used as a function name, the operator has been renamed `finalize` (as indicated by the documentation on <strike>lettable</strike> [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).